# Ошибка "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple"

Tags: python

Доброй ночи, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем реально ошибка, никак не знаю как перестроить код, чтобы работало. У меня есть телеграм бот, в нем есть message_handler через который я получаю результат(список с базы данных).
Это сам message_handler где ошибка:

```python
@dp.message_handler(text='Посмотреть номер в db')
async def check_database_bl_st(message: types.Message):
    data_bl_iez = id_database_work_registration.get_all_users_iez()
    users_iez = ''
    if data_bl_iez:
        for users_iez in data_bl_iez:
            for e in users_iez:
                users_iez += '|' + str(e)
            users_iez += '|\n'
    else:
        users_iez = 'В db нет записей!'
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_id, text=users_iez,
                           reply_markup=keyboards_app.admin_panel_iez)
```

А это сама функция через которую я запрашиваю вывод всех данных с таблицы БД:

```python
def get_all_users_iez(self):
        self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT id, number_IEZ, status_IEZ, date from users_information_iez;")
        users_date_1 = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.connection.commit()
        return users_date_1
```

Через символ "|" должны выводится данные с БД примерно так:
id | number_IEZ | status_IEZ | date |

Но в итоге ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы ошибки хоть читаете? Переведу: может объединять только кортежи, а вы по всей видимости пытаетесь провести конкатенацию кортежа и строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    users_iez = ''
    ^^^^^^^^^ строка
    if data_bl_iez:
        for users_iez in data_bl_iez:
            ^^^^^^^^^ кортеж
            for e in users_iez:
                     ^^^^^^^^^ кортеж
                users_iez += '|' + str(e)
                ^^^^^^^^^ кортеж, а предполагалась строка
```

У вас **одна и та же переменная** `users_iez` используется сразу **для двух целей** - и для накопления строковых данных и как переменная цикла, в которую попадает некий кортеж. Конечно же второе использование этой переменной перекрывает её старое строковое значение кортежем.
**Используйте две разных переменных** для накопления строки и для переменной цикла, не используйте одну переменную для двух разных целей.